# Setup Hubot integration for TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, hubot, tfs-2015

It is possible to get Hubot run with Visual Studio Online.
see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/hubot-and-vso-vs.aspx .

How to get the integration done for TFS 2015 (on-premise)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I expect you should be able to do it as the Service Hooks feature of VSO is in TFS 2015. You will probably be able to simplify it compared to VSO if you are running both TFS 2015 and Hubot on computers on your network (vs. over the Internet).